# Matrix outputs parts of it's tags on the frontend

Tags: matrix

After moving to a different server, i'm seeing strange output from Matrix. The output contains some of the ee tags and some of the html from within.

Here is the matrix tag pair:

```
{service_group_staff_quotes}
  <blockquote class="testimonial">
    {if photo}<img class="testimonial__media" src="{photo}" alt="{staff_credit}">{/if}
    <p class="testimonial__quote">“{staff_quote}”</p>
    <p class="testimonial__title">— {staff_credit}</p>
  </blockquote>
{/service_group_staff_quotes}
```

This is a screengrab of the output:

[image: description]

The '{s' at the beginning and the '/p>' at the end of the first para, then the '{sta' at the beginning of the second para are the problem. Anyone seen this before or got any ideas? I've tried running the EE server wizard on the new server which reports everything is fine and i've tried re-uploading the system folder incase anything got lost over FTP. Any help appreciated :)

EE 2.5.5, Matrix 2.5.10

Comment: What PHP version is running? Also does the same happen if you add a var_prefix ?

Comment: Cheers Sean, PHP 5.3.28 and yep, same issue when adding a var_prefix

Comment: Does this same snippet work in other templates? Are you using any other modules/plugins?  What happens when you just try doing: `{service_group_staff_quotes}{staff_quote}<br>{/service_group_staff_quotes}`

Comment: yep, that works but if i add another tag, it starts breaking again. Tried it on another template and got the same issue. I should add that this all works fine on our staging server

Comment: Have you tried rolling back to an older version of Matrix?

Comment: Might also be something to do with the staging and production server setups too?

Comment: Check the php recursion limits

Comment: Have been unable to find any problem with EE or with Matrix. We have now concluded the issue is with character encoding types and having looked at the sql(and encoding of data there), most likely something relating to PHP configuration. This occurred when we moved from a Ubuntu server to a RHEL server. I will update this if anything else useful comes to light. Thanks for Sean Delaney's extensive help with this in looking at the EE/Matrix side of things.

Answer (score 2):

The only time I've seen this behavior is when the text in the field contains foreign characters, like if its been pasted from Word but have seen it from other PC based apps with no rhyme nor reason.

Try deleting everything in the field and type it a new - don't copy paste.

PS. Just noticed the output - this may not help :(

Comment: This is the correct answer; the template above has "curly double-quotes;" as copied above, you have `“{staff_quote}”`, but actually need `"{staff_quote}"` If the fancier quotes are desired as output, then html-entify them as `&ldquo;` and `&rdquo;`